# Salesforce Custom Objects

Tags: salesforce

Hi I am trying to create a Custom Object in Salesforce.com Developer Edition, because I would then like to use this Custom Object in a New Custom Tab say "Properties".   Properties tab will contain information about Realestate Properties, like # of rooms, bath rooms etc.

The problem I cannot seem to get around is how do I create a Custom Object that has many attributes.  When I go to Setup->Create->Objects  it only has one Label in the Custom Object definition page.   I am expecting many attributes/labels I can add so I can then put this into the new Tab.

I've been looking at this for a while and I do not see a solution, so I am assuming I am looking at this wrong.  Could someone recommend a solution or a book, article that would show me what I am missing. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has a huge amount of publicly available training material available online.

The fundamentals doc should provide you with what you need immediately (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/index.htm).

I also recommend looking at the training courses available on iTunes (search for Salesforce).

Answer (score 10):

The custom objects page shows a list of all the custom objects you have created.  If you click on the label, it takes you to the object definition.  To add more attributes (called "fields" in Salesforce), go to the "Custom Fields & Relationships" section on the object detail page.  Click to "New" button to add new fields from there.